# How to export json data to excel in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to export a json data getting from a POST method in Angular JS to excel in .csv or .xls format?On click of a button?

Comment: yes it is possibly for example [ng-csv](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv)

Comment: i use ng-csv too. great module

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to send a request to your server and this one generates the file, for example csv, and add those headers to the request:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
```

Then your browser will download the file automatically.

If you need to generate the file in the browser you can use [ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) but in my opinion I would use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

before answering your question i would like to know what type of data you are exporting to excel or csv .

If u r using ng-csv directive then you can't export your data to excel files . If u are planning ahead to export in other file formats also then there ia a library u can use .

alasql.js

Here is a link if u are interesed to know more about this library

https://github.com/agershun/alasql